# Django: Override 404 template in some views

Tags: python, django

I have a custom 404 template for my whole django application but I would like to show a different one for specific views.

Is there a way to overrride the 404 template at runtime for one specific view?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
def not_found404(request, exception):
        data = {}
        if request.path == "/spesific-view-path/":
            return render(request, 'your_app/different_404.html', data)
        return render(request,'your_app/404.html', data)
```

main urls.py

```
handler404 = 'your_app.views.not_found404'
```